# Laravel Vite build error: 'resolve' is not exported by __vite-browser-externaL

Tags: node.js, laravel, vite, laravel-9, laravel-vite

I'm trying to build and version the assets for production in a Laravel project. I'm using laravel-vite-plugin version 0.6.1, node version v16.17.1, npm version 8.19.2. For this, when I run `npm run build`, I get the following error.

```
> 'resolve' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/vite/dist/node/constants.js
>     file: /var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/constants.js:1:15
>     1: import path, { resolve } from 'node:path';
>                     ^
>     2: import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
>     error during build:
>     Error: 'resolve' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/vite/dist/node/constants.js
>         at error (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)
>         at Module.error (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12429:16)
>         at Module.traceVariable (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12788:29)
>         at ModuleScope.findVariable (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:11440:39)
>         at Identifier.bind (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:7439:40)
>         at CallExpression.bind (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5269:23)
>         at CallExpression.bind (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:8935:15)
>         at VariableDeclarator.bind (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5269:23)
>         at VariableDeclaration.bind (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5265:73)
>         at Program.bind (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:5265:73)
```

### Below is my Vite configuration.

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/style.scss',
                'resources/scss/theme.scss',
                'resources/js/bundle.js',
                'resources/js/scripts.js',
                'resources/js/charts/analytics-chart.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is likely due to a compatibility issue between the version of Node.js you're using and the version of Vite.

Vite 2.7.0 and later versions have started using Node.js built-in modules (like 'node:path') which are only available in Node.js version 16.5.0 and later. However, these built-in modules are not fully supported in some environments, which can cause the error you're seeing.

To fix this issue, you can try downgrading Vite to a version that doesn't use Node.js built-in modules. For example, you can downgrade to Vite 2.6.14:

```bash
npm uninstall vite
npm install vite@2.6.14
```

Then try running `npm run build` again.

Alternatively, if you want to use the latest version of Vite, you can upgrade Node.js to the latest version (currently 17.3.0) or the latest LTS version (currently 16.13.1). However, please note that this might not solve the issue if your environment doesn't fully support Node.js built-in modules.